# JSF Template - Refreshing template components when changing view

Tags: jsf, templates, view, primefaces, facelets

I've got template which has: header, footer, menu (left side), cart (right side) and content at center. I select category from menu and send it via parameter to view page which overrides content from template. Then i use commandButton to add any product to cart. It works but next I select different category from menu view page updates with other products but my cart (included in template) does not. It remains as it was before when I was on the view page with this category. How can I overcome this problem? Thanks for any solution.

template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="category"/>
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
    <title>Drummers Store</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="top">
            <div id="top-content">
                <div style="text-align: left; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 20px;">
                    <a href="./index.xhtml"><p:graphicImage   value="./resources/images/logo.png"    height="80px" width="80px" /></a>
                </div>
                <h:form>
                    <p:menuButton style="font-size: 10px;" value="account_name">
                        <p:menuitem value="Account Settings" />
                        <p:separator />
                        <p:menuitem value="Logut" />
                    </p:menuButton>
                </h:form>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="left">
            <div id="left-content">
                <h:form id="form" style="width: 290px;" >
                    <p:panelMenu id="categories" style="text-align: center;">
                    <c:forEach items="#{dSServerBean.categories}" var="c">
                        <p:submenu label="#{c.category_name}">
                            <c:forEach items="#{c.sub_categories}" var="s">
                                <c:if test="#{not s.sub_categories.isEmpty()}">
                                    <p:submenu label="#{s.subCategory_name}">
                                        <c:forEach items="#{s.sub_categories}" var="si">
                                            <p:menuitem value="#{si.subCategory_name}"    outcome="productView">
                                                <f:param name="category" 
                                                         value="#{si.subCategory_name.toLowerCase()}" />
                                            </p:menuitem>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </p:submenu>                   
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="#{s.sub_categories.isEmpty()}"> 
                                    <p:menuitem value="#{s.subCategory_name}" outcome="productView">
                                        <f:param name="category" 
                                                         value="#{s.subCategory_name.toLowerCase()}" />
                                    </p:menuitem>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </c:forEach>
                </p:panelMenu>
            </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <div id="right-content">
                <h:form style="width: 85%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 50px;">
                    <p:panel>
                        <f:facet name="header">Cart</f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="footer">To pay: 0 $</f:facet>  
                        <p:scrollPanel id="scroll2"
                                       style="height: 200px; 
                                       max-height: 200px; 
                                       overflow-wrap: break-word;">
                        <p:dataGrid value="#{dSBean.cart}" var="p" 
                                    columns="1" emptyMessage="No products added..."
                                    style="border: 0;">
                                <h:panelGrid>
                                    <h:outputText style="font-size: 10px;" value="#{p.name}" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:dataGrid>
                        </p:scrollPanel>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="center">
            <div id="center-content">
                <ui:insert name="content" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
            <div id="bottom-content">
                <p style="padding: 1px;">Copyright &copy; <b>Drummers Store</b> 2013</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</h:body>

</html>
```

view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="category"/>
</f:metadata>
<body>
    <ui:composition template="./templates/mainLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="right">
            right
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>  
                <p:scrollPanel id="scroll1" style="height: 700px; max-height: 700px; width: 100%;">
                    <p:dataGrid value="#{dSServerBean.getProducts(param.category)}" 
                                var="product" columns="1">
                        <p:panel header="#{product.name}">
                            <h:panelGrid style="width:100%;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{product.description}" />

                                <h:commandButton value="DODAJ" action="#{dSBean.addToCart(product)}" >
                                    <f:param name="category" value="#{param.category}" />
                                </h:commandButton>

                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:dataGrid>              
                </p:scrollPanel>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

DSServerBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class DSServerBean {

public Set<Category> categories = new CategoriesTemplate().categoriesTemplate;
public static Set<Product> products = new ProductsTemplate().productsTemplate;
public Map<String, Set<Product>> category_products;

public DSServerBean() {
    category_products = new TreeMap<>();

    for(Category category : categories){
        category_products.put(category.getCategory_name().toLowerCase(), new TreeSet<Product>());
        for(SubCategory subCategory : category.getSub_categories()){
            category_products.put(subCategory.getSubCategory_name().toLowerCase(), new TreeSet<Product>());
            for(SubCategory subSubCategory : subCategory.getSub_categories()){
                category_products.put(subSubCategory.getSubCategory_name().toLowerCase(), new TreeSet<Product>());
            }
        }
    }

    for(Product product : products){
        for(String category : product.getCategories().split(",")){
            category_products.get(category).add(product);
        }
    }
}

public Set<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public Map<String, Set<Product>> getCategory_products() {
    return category_products;
}

public List<Product> getProducts(String category){
    List<Product> view = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Product p : category_products.get(category))
        view.add(p);
    return view;
}
}
```

DSBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DSBean {

private User logged_user;
private List<Product> cart;

public DSBean(){
    logged_user = new User("Marian");
    cart = new ArrayList<>();
}

public User getLogged_user() {
    return logged_user;
}

public List<Product> getCart() {
    return cart;
}

    //METHODS

public String addToCart(String product){
    System.out.println(product);
    for(Product p : DSServerBean.products)
        if(p.toString().equals(product))
            cart.add(p);
    return "productView";
}


}
```

Comment: Without showing `dSServerBean` code, it is hard say where problem is. Please show the code of dSServerBean.

Comment: DsServerBean has tree set with categories, and tree map<category, set<product>>. At now its only used to return array list with products for given category. Its Application scoped. Sure Ill post its code when i got back home.

Comment: don't you have double `<body>` tags, in the tamplate and in the view? And yet only visible part of the view is that inside `<ui:define name="content">`

Comment: An idea: Wrap the contents of the basket page in a form, and in the commandButton's update tag, add ":basketForm" to redraw the basket via ajax. However @Masud is right - without the backing bean code to hand, it is hard to see what you've done and what is going wrong for you.

Comment: @7SpecialGems he could always `update="@all"`

Comment: @Kuba, it's said JSF removes all tags outside <ui:composition> or I'm wrong?

Comment: @7SpecialGems It's not a problem with updating basket after clicking commandButton, coz it updates. Problem is for eg. I select one category from menu then add some products to cart by clicking commandButton then I change category from menu and then cart isn't updated. It's empty or shows products from old session (sometimes even i make clear one). So everytime I need to refresh page.

Comment: @Maciej yes and no. If you include certain part of your view in a template, then template takes what it needs - `<ui:define name="content">`. In your case you could skip everything outside of `<ui:composition>` and include `xmlns`s in `<ui:composition>` tag.

Comment: @Kuba Already did it. Same result, but I found that when outcome atribute to change view isn't used (just replaced it with action="page_name") the problem is solved. However as I remember p:menuitem doesn't redirect to other view via action attribute and I would like to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'll found alternative solution, just as I mentioned before. I change view via action attribute (instead outcome attribute) of menuitem which has linked parameter which I obtain in managed bean (not in view like before). Thanks for interest.